# Does the English translation of Bourbaki make sense?

Tags: set-theory

I tried reading the English translation of Bourbaki's theory of sets. and I am confused, there is little that makes sense to me. I have experience with Naive set theory, so I was looking forward to learning ZFC and surrounding schemes with some rigour but this is too complex and inconsistent.I am looking forward to some dialogue where I get to know something.

Comment: I do not think that the English translation is mistaken in general... But B's treatment of set theory is not "usual" ZFC.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If you want to learn set theory, and a ZFC style one in particular, Bourbaki is one of the worst choices of sources.

Comment: It might be helpful to provide the OP with some alternatives. I think (and please correct me if I'm wrong) Jech's book _Set Theory: The Third Millennium edition_ is probably one of the best books for learning ZFC at a graduate level.

Comment: Not to toot my own horn, but I also have lecture notes from a course I gave about ZFC available on my website. There is also a list of sources in the "The Five WH's of Set Theory".

Comment: Derek Goldrei's *Classic Set Theory: For Guided Independent Study* is a good intro to ZFC especially if you're not taking a formal course on set theory

Comment: The main purpose of the Bourbaki association was to unify mathematics, they named mathematics as "The Mathematic", as a whole (in the singular and not in the plural). This implied an intellectual effort unprecedented in the history of human culture and could not have been undertaken without certain modifications in the approach to the various topics at stake, with which not a few not french mathematicians disagreed.

Comment: @Piquito: While all good and true, their treatment of set theory (and logic) was especially bad.

Comment: I would recomend Endertons textbook on set theory, and if that is too elementary- try Kunen's textbook, An Introduction to Independence Proofs. Jechs manuscript on Set Theory is fantastic, but it is also monolithic- and I wouldn't recomend  it to someone self studying unless they were very motivated.